# Is it possible to automatically handle List.Contains by comparing a property on the item?

Tags: c#, list, equals, contains, iequatable

Can we do something similar to `List.Contains(myItem)` in order to check if a property on an item in the list equals a property on `myItem`.

(We have considered `Contains` and `Exists`, something like:

```
if (orderLines.Contains(myLine)) { ... }
```

but cannot get a simple expression.)

We would like something as simple as the following:

```
if (orderLines.[MethodName](myLine))
{
}
```

and this method should automagically return true if at least one item `orderLines[i]` fulfills:

```
myLine.Product.Equals(orderLines[i].Product)
```

We have implemented `IEquatable<OrderLine>` which equates by the `Product` property, but cannot find how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using .NET 3.5? If so, use LINQ:

```
if (orderLines.Any(order => order.Product == myLine.Product))
{
    ...
}
```